# Source for updated rails engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the source (url) for Rails Engines that works with rails 2.2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd get the current source from [github](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master) and search for "engine".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Rails Guides did not start until Rails 2.3.8. I could not find guides for anything less than Rails 2.3.8.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8.

Additionally, Rails Engines were something introduced in Rails 2.3, though similar functionality may have been present in Rails 2.2 through Plugins.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines?autoplay=false